# How to invert a multidimensional array stored in NetCDF along 1 dimension?

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array, netcdf, netcdf4

I have netCDF containing multidimensional array of following shape:

[1:424, 1:412, 1:3, 1:130]

..and I would like to invert along 2nd dimension and get:

[1:424, 412:1, 1:3, 1:130]

I tried:

```
test_object <- nc_open("~/work/macro/COOR_2_INDICES/test.nc")
hwmid <- ncvar_get(test_object)
    
hwmid<-hwmid[,412:1,,]

nc_close( test_object )
```

..but this does not invert the object and also I am not getting any error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your code you read the data into your R workspace and inverted the data, but you never wrote it back to the NetCDF-file.
Assuming that your variable is called "hwmid" in the NetCDF-file, you can write to the file after inverting using:

```
ncvar_put(nc = test_object,
    varid = "hwmid",
    vals = hwmid,
    start = c(1,1,1,1),
    count = c(424, 412, 3, 130))
```

Comment: Thanks... this was other part of my question indirectly there - I was missing also this... But the problem is that the "hwmid" object remains non-inverted after hwmid<-hwmid[,412:1,,]... I am sharing the file by following link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByPJ-UkVdXZgUl9TRmdwb2hDaXc

Comment: OK... it turn out that converting was alright (as in Heikki's answer)... and the only part missing was ncvar_put... which worked perfectly... so I down-voted solution... again.. I am sorry Tobias and thanks again for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting that the object is of type array, the order of incices can be changed as follows in the three dimensional example below:

```
> three_d_array <- array(
+   1:8,
+   dim = c(2, 2, 2),
+   dimnames = list(
+     c("one", "two"),
+     c("ein", "zwei"),
+     c("un", "deux")
+   )
+ )
> three_d_array[,1:2,]
, , un

    ein zwei
one   1    3
two   2    4

, , deux

    ein zwei
one   5    7
two   6    8

> three_d_array <- three_d_array[,2:1,]
> three_d_array
, , un

    zwei ein
one    3   1
two    4   2

, , deux

    zwei ein
one    7   5
two    8   6
```

Similar behaviour should take place also in higher dimensions.

Comment: This was not what I wanted (swapping the dimensions) ...I need to invert just 1 dimension (latitudes)... basically I have Europe "upside-down" ...but thanks a lot for your effort anyway!